# I came across an old basis post, clarification?

Tags: general-topology

I came across this old post and I'm currently trying to understand bases.

[A basis for some topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188601/a-basis-for-some-topology-on-mathbbr2)

I don't understand why in the rewrite of the equation you clarified that:

> ...such that $a<c$ and $b<d$...

In that case, what would be a similar method of solution for something like this?

$$\mathcal{B}= \{(x,y): a\leq x<b, c \leq y<d\}$$ for $a<b$ and $c<d$.

I'm not sure I'm getting my head around the part where you show it directly using the conditions defining a base for a topology for something like the above case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $p=\langle a,b\rangle$ and $q=\langle c,d\rangle$. We want to use these two points to define a box $B(p,q)$ whose lower lefthand corner is $p$ and whose upper righthand corner is $q$. Moreover, we want this box to include its top and righthand edges but not its left or bottom edge. These conditions require that $p$ be below and to the left of $q$, which in turn means that we must have $a<c$ (so that $p$ is to the left of $q$) and $b<d$ (so that $p$ is below $q$).

We could instead use $p$ and $q$ to define a box

$$B\,'(p,q)=\left\{\langle x,y\rangle:a\le x<b\text{ and }c\le y<d\right\}\;;$$

this box would also have $p$ as its lower lefthand corner and $q$ as its upper righthand corner, but it would include its left and bottom edges and exclude its top and righthand edges. We could then let $\mathscr{B}\,'$ be the collection of all such $B\,'(p,q)$.

(Note that your $\mathcal{B}$ is just one box, so the use of a script letter for it is rather odd: conventionally one expects a script letter to denote a whole collection of sets.)

To show that this family $\mathscr{B}\,'$ is a base for a topology on $\Bbb R^2$, you can copy the arguments in [my earlier answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/188608/12042) with very little change. For instance, you’ll have to replace $(x-1,x]$ with $[x,x+1)$ in the paragraph near the end beginning *To verify (1)*. $\Bbb R^2$ with this topology is known as the [Sorgenfrey plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_plane) and is a fairly important example in topology.